# Valid HTML/HTML5 tags inside Unordered list

Tags: html, html-lists, w3c-validation

I am not sure about the validation of tags inside **li of ul**, basically i want containers like **div, section, aside, article, p, h's etcs** inside a li, but i am not sure keeping these into the li, will be a valid code...

**The code:-**

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <figure><img src="images/me.jpg" alt="Image" /></figure>
      /* WHAT ELSE */
   </li>
</ul>
```

Till now i know that **figure, a, span, strong, em, small, etcs** are valid...

But i am not sure about the other tags valid or not?

Can i have the suggestions for this what to use and what not to use??

Comment: So why don't you validate yourself on w3c? It's free...

Comment: @Mr.Alien i dnt want to validate, want to know what are the valid tags inside li...

Comment: So that's what w3c will answer you whether they are valid or not, why depend on others answers when you've w3c answering?

Comment: i cant find any documentation regarding this?

Comment: Don't you know w3c validator?

Comment: @SaurabhLP: You totally miss that there is no specification of valid tags in HTML5, it's a living standard. You *need* to ask the validator because all this HTML5 is subject to change (and btw current version is 5.1) - If you are concerned to a specific revision of the specs - which has not been written in your question - you can just relate to the links the validator gives you to the specs.

Comment: @hakre — The validator tracks the HTML 5 specification. If there are changes, then the validator may be out of date while the specification won't be. Validators are not more reliable then reading the specification.

Comment: @Quentin: I've never seen that the validator being out of date would ever cause any problems at all. So saying it's "out of date" is creating a wrong impression IMHO.

Comment: @hakre — There are reasons that the valdator's HTML 5 mode is labeled Experimental.

Comment: And the standard is called living. Which hardly makes it obsoleting itself as a constant of specification. So the validator does well to label itself experimental - everything else would be creating a wrong image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proper knowledge you have to use specs of HTML (whatever).

[HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)

[The li element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) tell us that content model is [Flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1).

Comment: thanks for reply, so from this documentation figure tag is not valid inside li, but i didnt see any alternative tags other than a span...

Comment: @SaurabhLP — Wrong. `figure` appears in the list of elements that constitute Flow content that the answer links to.

Comment: @Quentin okay got that what else i can use other than figure, could me mention them and answer in html/html5 both...

Comment: I have no idea what "could me mention them and answer" means. "HTML" and "HTML 5" are not different things. "HTML 4" and "HTML 5" are (slightly) different things, but both are "HTML".